# Count() inside 'for-each' always returns zero

Tags: xslt-2.0

Currently, I have many "xsl:choose" conditions in my file - one "xsl:choose" for a single letter, and it works well.
I try to simplify this situation by replacing many "xsl:choose" with 'for-each' loop - however with no luck.

It's seems to me, that count() inside 'for-each' always returns 0.
I'm curious, because the same count() without 'for-each' works OK.

Pls help.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<stocks>
<names date="10/30/2013" time="20:37:12">
    <name>WGOS1</name>
    <name>WGOS2</name>
    <name>WGOS3</name>
    <name>WGOS4</name>
    <name>WGOS5</name>
</names>
<loc>
    <slot>P</slot>
    <slot>P</slot>
    <slot>P</slot>
    <slot>P</slot>
    <slot>H</slot>
    <slot>S</slot>
</loc>
<loc>
    <slot>P</slot>
    <slot>P</slot>
    <slot>P</slot>
    <slot>S</slot>
```

When I use 'count' function to count values eg. 'B' in 'loc' node, it's works OK

```
<xsl:variable name="color-table">
    <var code="A">pink</var  >
    <var code="B">silver</var>
    <var code="P">red</var>
    <var code="D">pink</var>
    <var code="H">yellow</var>
    <var code="S">lightblue</var>
    <var code="T">green</var>
    <var code="W">pink</var>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="/">    

<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="count(/stocks/loc[$pos]/slot [. eq 'B']) &gt; 0">
        <td class="slot-B">
            <xsl:value-of select="count(/stocks/loc[$pos]/slot [. eq 'B'])"/>
            <xsl:text>B</xsl:text>
        </td>
    </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
```

But when I try to do the same inside for-each loop - test condition fails, due the count() result is always 0.

```
    <xsl:for-each select="$color-table/var">
    <xsl:variable name="p" select="@code"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="count(/stocks/loc[$pos]/slot [. eq $p]) &gt; 0">
            <td class="slot-$p">
                <xsl:value-of select="count(/stocks/loc[$pos]/slot [. eq $p])"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="$p"/>
            </td>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `$color-table` variable refers to a temporary tree, so when you're inside a

```
<xsl:for-each select="$color-table/var">
```

`/` is the root of that temporary tree, not the root of the original document, and thus `/stocks/loc[$pos]/slot` will not find any nodes.

You need to store the outer `/` in another variable before you go into the `for-each`.

```
<xsl:variable name="slash" select="/" />
<xsl:for-each select="$color-table/var">
<xsl:variable name="p" select="@code"/>
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="count($slash/stocks/loc[$pos]/slot [. eq $p]) &gt; 0">
        <td class="slot-{$p}">
            <xsl:value-of select="count($slash/stocks/loc[$pos]/slot [. eq $p])"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$p"/>
        </td>
    </xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each>
```

But rather than iterating over the color-table, it may be more efficient to just `for-each-group` over the slots themselves

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="/stocks/loc[$pos]/slot" group-by=".">
  <td class="slot-{current-grouping-key()}">
    <xsl:value-of select="count(current-group())" />
    <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()" />
  </td>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

Comment: I guess the `<td class="slot-$p">` should be `<td class="slot-{$p}">`, although that is not part of the question.

Comment: @MartinHonnen that would indeed make more sense.